# Can I have one table in multiple clusters?

Tags: oracle, database-design

I am wondering if it is possible (or recommended), to cluster one table into many clusters? Lets say I have some schema like that:

```
Employees (Id_emp, First Name, Last Name, DateOfBirth, Address)
Employment (Id_emp, Data_start, position Date_end, Earnings)
Products (Id_product, Name, Price, Quantity)
Customers (Id_client, Name, Last Name, Address)
Sales (Id_sale, Id_client, Id_product, Number, Date, Id_emp)
```

I am wondering if it is possible to create those clusters:

```
Employees+Employment on Id_emp;
Sales+Products on Id_product;
Sales+Customers on Id_client;
Sales+Employees on Id_emp;
```

My question arises, because I am not sure If I am able to create 3 clusters, which all have `Sales` in themselves.

Any answers are more than welcome!